# .NET core asp-for radio button bound to model with clickable labels?

Tags: html, asp.net, .net, label

I wanted to make a radio button list which is bound to a model in asp.net core.  But, I also wanted the unique labels to be clickable and associated with each radio button.  I have this:

```
  <fieldset>
      <div>
          <span>
              <input type="radio" required asp-for="Email" value="EmailYes" /> <b>Send Email:</b> They will be sent an email.
          </span>
      </div>
      <div>
          <span>
              <input type="radio" required asp-for="Email" value="EmailNo" /> <b>Do Not Send Email:</b> They will not be sent an email.
          </span>
      </div>
  </fieldset>
```

I've tried adding a label like so:

```
  <label asp-for="EmailYes"><b>Send Email:</b> They will be sent an email. </label>
```

But when the user clicks on the second label, it selects the first radio button.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Got it:

```
<fieldset>
  <div>
      <span>
          <input type="radio" required asp-for="Email" id="EmailYes" value="EmailYes" />
          <label for="EmailYes"><b>Send Email:</b> They will be sent an email. /label> 
      </span>
  </div>
  <div>
      <span>
          <input type="radio" required asp-for="Email" id="EmailNo" value="EmailNo" />
          <label for="EmailNo"><b>Do Not Send Email:</b> They will not be sent an email. /label>
      </span>
  </div>
```

I was hoping to use only .NET Core Tag Helpers, but this works.

Comment: This answer is still relevant today!